# How can I make an -[NSURLCache cachedResponseForRequest:] work with redirected requests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, http, nsurlcache

I'm using an NSURLCache for storing images that are used in collection view cells. When a cell is presented, I want to be able to get the cached image for a particular cell (which has a URL for that image associated with it). I can do this using `-[NSURLCache cachedResponseForRequest:]`, but the problem is that if the server returns a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently response, that method returns a cached response which describes the redirect, not the second follow-up response which contains the actual image data. Is there any easy way to get the cached data for a redirected HTTP request from an `NSURLCache`?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a built-in way to solve this problem, so I created a category on `NSURLCache`, which recursively follows HTTP redirects:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)nf_cachedResponseForRequestByFollowingRedirects:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [self cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPURLResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)cachedResponse.response;

    if ([@[@301, @302, @303, @307, @308] containsObject:@(HTTPURLResponse.statusCode)])
    {
        NSString *redirectedURL = HTTPURLResponse.allHeaderFields[@"Location"];
        if (redirectedURL.length > 0)
        {
            NSMutableURLRequest *redirectedRequest = request.mutableCopy;
            redirectedRequest.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:redirectedURL];
            return [self nf_cachedResponseForRequestByFollowingRedirects:redirectedRequest];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Warning: got a redirected URL response, but without a 'Location' field to redirect to. Headers: %@", HTTPURLResponse.allHeaderFields);
            return cachedResponse;
        }
    }
    return cachedResponse;
}
```

*Note: this solution could cause infinite recursion (and stack overflow) in case of a redirect loop.*